# Filter <br> tag using BeautifulSoup4 in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a website with a table holding a number of `td`'s looking like:

```
...
<td class="click"><span class="content">VALUE | KEY<br />2020-02-02</span></td>
...
```

I am using BeautifulSoup to read its content, which currently prints as: `VALUE | KEY2020-02-02`.

The code to achieve this looks like:

```
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        cols = []
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            td_text = td.get_text()
            if len(td_text):
                cols.append(td_text)
    temp.append(cols)
```

Ultimately, what I would like to achieve is being able to print out as: `VALUE|KEY|2020-02-02` - or, in other words, replace the `<br />` tag with `|` so I can keep `VALUE`, `KEY` and `2020-02-02` separated. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Where do you see the `br` tag? is prints as VALUE | KEY2020-02-02.. So get_text() has successfully removed it, right? Or you mean you wish to replace the tag with `|`?

Comment: I do apologise if my description is not clear: I would indeed like to replace the tag with `|` as that allows me to split things.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aim to replace the `br` tags with a `|`, you could do the following:

```
for br_tag in soup.findAll('br'):
    br_tag.replace_with('|')
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your suggestion. Applying this however removes everything following the `br` tag - unless I am doing something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the `<td>` element and then calling the `get_text()` function which returns all the printable text inside (stripping the span).  Instead you can select the `<span>` element, get the HTML string representation (by calling `str()` on the element, and then splitting on `<br/>`) like this:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = []
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        span_html = str(td.find_all('span')).split('<br />')
```

Comment: Would I be able to implement this so I can also handle other `td`'s in the same table without `br`'s?

Comment: If you have two types of of cells you might be able to write a regular expression that can solve multiple row types.